# How to pass every user input to the Bing spell check and then send it to LUIS for processing.( Nodejs SDK v3)?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot

I found this sample code

```
var https = require ('https');
var msg = new builder.Message(session);
var host = 'api.cognitive.microsoft.com';
var path = '/bing/v7.0/spellcheck';

/* NOTE: Replace this example key with a valid subscription key (see the                 Prequisites section above). Also note v5 and v7 require separate subscription keys. */
var key = '****************';

var mkt = "en-US";
var mode = "proof";
var text = "nthgn can b done";
var query_string = "?mkt=" + mkt + "&mode=" + mode;

var request_params = {
method : 'POST',
hostname : host,
path : path + query_string,
headers : {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length' : text.length + 5,
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : key,
//        'X-Search-Location' : CLIENT_LOCATION,
//        'X-MSEdge-ClientID' : CLIENT_ID,
//        'X-MSEdge-ClientIP' : CLIENT_ID,
}
};

var response_handler = function (response) {
var body = '';
response.on ('data', function (d) {
    body += d;
});
response.on ('end', function () {
    console.log (body);
});
response.on ('error', function (e) {
    console.log ('Error: ' + e.message);
});
};

var req = https.request (request_params, response_handler);
req.write ("text=" + text);
req.end ();
```

1.How do I send every user input to the text?

2.Is it possible to display correct spelling on the chat window after the processing?

3.How do I send this to LUIS?

Any help with the documents or links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LUIS has Bing Spell-check built-in.

You can enable it in the LUIS dashboard by going to:

> Manage > Keys and Endpoints

Then, enable "Bing Spell Check"

[image: Bing spell check radio toggle]

Anytime you use `builder.EntityRecognizer` or `builder.IntentRecognizer`, the input will first go to Bing to be spell-checked, then sent to LUIS for intent and entity recognition (Answers question 3).

Here's an example of the response I got from LUIS when spelling "seattle" as "seatle" (missing a "t").

```
{
  "query": "seatle",
  "alteredQuery": "seattle",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Help",
    "score": 0.340962738
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Help",
      "score": 0.340962738
    },
    {
      "intent": "SearchHotels",
      "score": 0.274775743
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.03235885
    },
    {
      "intent": "ShowHotelsReviews",
      "score": 0.00128200091
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "seattle",
      "type": "builtin.geographyV2.city",
      "startIndex": 0,
      "endIndex": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see that it corrected the spelling to "seattle" in `alteredQuery` and returned "seattle" as the correct entity towards the bottom under `entity` (Answers question 3).

I tested this on [one of the V3 sample bots](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples/Node/intelligence-LUIS). Note, though, that the linked bot doesn't use LUIS for spell-checking, but provides an alternate way to use the Bing Spell Check API (Answers your question 1). To have this bot use LUIS' integrated Bing Spell Checking, leave the `IS_SPELL_CORRECTION_ENABLED` flag in `.env` set to `false`, then set the `LUIS_MODEL_URL` to include your bing subscription key, like so:

```
LUIS_MODEL_URL=https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/{LUIS-APP-ID}?spellCheck=true&bing-spell-check-subscription-key={BING-SPELL-CHECK-KEY}&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=-360&subscription-key={LUIS-SUBSCRIPTION-KEY}&q=
```

**Additional Documentation:**

[Recognize intent with LUIS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

[Bing Spell Check Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-spell-check/quickstarts/nodejs)